# I got this msg while using F# query expression : error FS0039: Undefined value or constructor “query”

Tags: f#, query-expressions

```
let q = <@  seq {
                for i in [1..10] do
                    yield i  
        } |> Seq.head @>

q |> query |> ignore  //error FS0039
```

I'am using VS2012 and F# core of `"ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll"` (version 2.3.0.0)
on .NET 3.5 ;

What did I miss here?

Comment: Doing `open System.Linq` will fix that problem, but there is another type related error left that I am not sure about.

Comment: Thank you for your help,John Palmer.I turn the target .NET framework to .NET 4.5 and than query got it's definition.Maybe it's not available under .net 3.5 and lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong (the versioning is a bit confusing) but if you're using  F# 3.0 in Visual Studio 2012, then you should be able to use the new query expression syntax instead:

```
query { for i in 1 .. 10 do
        select i
        head }
```

This works both in memory and for SQL databases (as well as some type providers). For more information, see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh225374.aspx). If you're using older version (or target framework), then I'd definitely recommend upgrading - the F# 3.0 queries are much more solid and easy to use.

Comment: You are right. Actually i thought that all features of F# 3.0 available for .NET 2.0.